# Residue theorem and integral

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, calculus

I am studying complex analysis and I saw integral like this
$$
y = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{s\cdot \mathrm{exp}(ist)}{s^2-z^2}ds.
$$

And this integral has clearly two poles $s=z$ and $s=-z$. I know how to calculate this using residue theorem, but in every source they claim that for $s>0$, we have to integral using upper contour and 'removing' pole $s=-k$. And for the $s<0$, the situation is opposite. I know that it has something in common with boundary conditions. Can somebody explaine me, why for $s>0$ we have to use upper contour and include only one pole?

Comment: Looks like a question for [math.se].

Comment: Integral should be evaluated in PV sense; therefore, we have to take only half of the residues at $s=z$ and $s=-z$ (to make a close contour we have to add two small half-circles around $s=z$ and $s=-z$, and we have to extract these integrals along small circles from the $\oint$ value).

Comment: To make the program easy we can rewrite the integral: $I(t,z)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Big(\frac{1}{s-z}+\frac{1}{s+z}\Big)e^{ist}ds$. Then making changes $s\pm z =p$ in the first and second integral correspondingly: $I=\frac{1}{2}\big(e^{itz}+e^{-itz}\big)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ipt}}{p}dp$. Adding a small half-circle below $p=0$ and a big half-circle of radius R in the upper half-plane (we suppose $t>o$ - to use Jordan's lemma), we can evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ipt}}{p}dp=\pi i$. Therefore, $I(z,t)=\pi i\cos(tz)$